# C# Close Console in WPF application not closing app

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling, console

I'm making a WPF application, and i made possibility to write log in Console (or .txt file if user wants).

I'm creating Console instance using kernel32.dll's methods: `AllocConsole(); FreeConsole(); GetConsoleWindow(); GetConsoleOutputCP();`.

But if user closes Console my app closes either, but that is not what i want.

I tried using kernel32.dll's `SetConsoleCtrlHandler()` method or standard WPF events (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`, `App.Current.Exit`) but none of them catches Console closing event.

Is there a way to do this? Or should loggin to Console be implemented by using `echo` in cmd process?

Answer (score 0):

You can start a process(cmd.exe, with optionally your app or command as parameter). Therefore you can write into the standart input of the console and you will be noticed about the events.